# how to put google+ photos with Json & google API

Tags: javascript, json, google-plus

i have a problem with the Google API.
I want to put pictures of a public album (google+) in some background-image in js.
i am not really familiar with Json

```
   var data = $.getJSON('https://plus.google.com/photos/ACCOUNT_ID/albums/ALBUM_ID');
      function displayGallery(data){
         var l = data.feed.entry.length; 
         for (var i = 0; i < l;  i++) {   
           var item = data.feed.entry[i];                         
           $('#m'+ i ).css("backround-image",data);
         }
```

i saw a similar post : [Using jQuery $.getJSON() with Google Picasa Data API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352971/using-jquery-getjson-with-google-picasa-data-api)
But it was hard to understand it (and excuse my english).

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: did you call the function `displayGallery` anywhere inside the script?  right now you only build it but not using it..

Comment: i used code found without really understand it.
But how can i parse my album url and how can i getback the image url to put it on <img>

Comment: Could you update your post with the hole code? the html and css would help as well

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have time to continue this project, but i think i finally took the right direction. I pretty close to the result i want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log("hello world");
   $.get('https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/userID/albumid/albuID', function(data){
        var entries = data.getElementsByTagName('entry');
        console.log(entries);
        // var entry = entries[0];
        for(var i =0; i< entries.length; i++){
                console.log(entries[i]);
                console.log($(entries[i].getElementsByTagName('content')[0]).attr("src"));

        }
  });

});
```

The only real problem is that there is a security on web browser  that doesnt permit you to well acces to this infos . You need to desable web security